# Is this how I should use the .next( [selector] ) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I have selected an `<a>` inside a div and want to use `$(this)` to select the next div (I guess this makes it an uncle?).

I want to use the same class name for all my content so I want to use only relative to `$(this)`.

Here's an example of the behavior I am after:

```
<div><a>click</a></div>
<div> SELECT THIS DIV after click a </div>  (real code below)
```

I have been playing around and it works fine if I don't close the div around the `<a>`. `.next('div")` finds the div after the `</a>`, but I need to close the div of the `<a>`.  (So I guess this makes the `<a>` a child of the div I am in.)

So I need to access the uncle div of the one I'm in?  How would I do that -

Here's what I have been playing with so far:

js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.demo > .row').hide();  
  $('.demo > .box > a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="demo">
    <div class="box"><a>Title 1</a></div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul >
            <li> <a >  <img >  </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/DtvL5/)?

Comment: .closest('div') works as parent in this case - Im still trying to work it all out.  So Instead of .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');  I need to hide the 1st cousins.  Is there a simple way?  Im thinking .parent.siblings.children.not$this.slideUp('fast'); ????

Comment: Hmm... stop explaining it like that. Explain to us through the DOM, say if I click on `a` element inside the `div.box`, which element should be hidden and which should be shown. That is, explain it in functionality what should happen when you do what!

Comment: click    a show only the next div.row but hide all other div.row  I updated the fiddle with the title 2 & 2nd content

Comment: I updated the fiddle again - I put the js in so it closes all the showing divs.  Im at a loss to tell it not to hide the div i just opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) provided by jQuery. In this case, you need [`parent`](http://api.jquery.org/parent) followed by [`next`](http://api.jquery.org/next):

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the document tree upwards from the "current" `<a>` to its parent `<div>`, and then sideways to find the next `<div>`:

```
$(this).closest("div").next().slideToggle('fast')
       .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
```

[Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) upwards can be done with a number of functions; I prefer [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) because it's less susceptive to breaking if your markup changes.

Also, note that if you click on an anchor child of the last sibling `<div>`, the `next()` call will not produce any element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)?

Something like `$(this).parent().next();`

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'uncle', you need to first get the parent, then the sibling.

```
$(this).parent('div').next('div')
```

Or, if the `a` is nested in other elements, you can use `closest` to get the parent `div`.

```
$(this).closest('div').next('div')
```